# Get particluar User Preferences stored in table in CheckBoxList as Selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am storing values of user preference in one column of table separated by `,`  example `Football,Tennis,Swimming,Hiking`

Table UserPreference

```
ID  USERID  Preferences
1   X1234   Football,Tennis,Swimming,Hiking
2   X2345   Cricket
3   X3456   Dancing,Reading
4   X4567   Games,Cricket,Tennis
```

Preferences are stored in table and i need to show particular user preference as  `Selected` in CheckBoxList in asp.net webform application so that user can see his preference or update them if he/she wants

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLstPrefences" runat="server" DataTextField="Preferences" DataValueField="Preferences" >
```

I am not sure how to  make it work I am reading user preference and converting them into string array but i am not sure how to match and show selected items to users in CheckBoxList

for example for user `X1234`

```
string sUserPreferences = "Football,Tennis,Swimming,Hiking"

string[] strAryUserPreferences = sUserPreferences.Split(',');
```

how to match user preferences in `strAryUserPreferences` with values in CheckBoxList chkLstPrefences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store value of column in some List and then loop through each items of ChkListPreference with the each value of stored in lstPrefList as nested for  loop and when any value match mark the it as Selected in ChkListPreference

```
// store value in lstPrefList
List<string> lstPrefList = ValuesFromDB;
  
if ((chkLstPrefences.Items.Count > 0) && (lstPrefList.Count > 0))
{
    for (int i2=0; i2 <chkLstPrefences.Items.Count; i2++)
    {
        for ( int i=0; i <lstPrefList.Count; i++)
        {
           if (chkLstPrefences.Items[i2].Value.ToString().Trim() == lstPrefList[i].ToString().Trim())
            {
                chkLstPrefences.Items[i2].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can bind domain to your checkboxlist, and then loop through each checkboxlist item and verify if is in your user preferences.
Something like this (sorry if it's no perfect but I've not visual studio now)..

```
var userPreferences = sUserPreferences.Split(',').ToList(); 
chkLstPrefences.DataSource = preferencesDomain;
chkLstPrefences.DataBind();
foreach(var item in chkLstPrefences.Items)
    item.Selected = userPreferences.Contains(item.Text);
```